# How is multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore different from multiprocessing.Manager().BoundedSemaphore?

Tags: python, python-2.7, semaphore, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to understand the difference between `multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore` and `multiprocessing.Manager().BoundedSemaphore`.

Here is a program that uses `multiproessing.BoundedSemaphore`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
import time

def f(i, sem):
    print 'worker %d is working ...' % i
    time.sleep(5)
    sem.release()
    print 'worker %d is done' % i

def master():

    plist = []
    sem = multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore(3)

    for i in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(i, sem))
        sem.acquire()
        p.start()
        plist.append(p)

    print 'waiting for processes to join ...'
    for p in plist:
        p.join()

    print 'master is done'

master()
print 'script is done'
```

Here is the output.

```
$ python sem1.py 
worker 0 is working ...
worker 1 is working ...
worker 2 is working ...
worker 0 is done
worker 1 is done
worker 2 is done
worker 3 is working ...
worker 4 is working ...
worker 5 is working ...
worker 3 is done
worker 4 is done
worker 5 is done
worker 6 is working ...
worker 7 is working ...
worker 8 is working ...
worker 6 is done
worker 7 is done
worker 8 is done
waiting for processes to join ...
worker 9 is working ...
worker 9 is done
master is done
script is done
```

Now I change just the semaphore creation code from:

```
    sem = multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore(3)
```

to

```
    sem = multiprocessing.Manager().BoundedSemaphore(3)
```

I run the new program again. It produces the same output as before with the same behavior as before. Here is the complete program with this change.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
import time

def f(i, sem):
    print 'worker %d is working ...' % i
    time.sleep(5)
    sem.release()
    print 'worker %d is done' % i

def master():

    plist = []
    sem = multiprocessing.Manager().BoundedSemaphore(3)

    for i in range(10):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(i, sem))
        sem.acquire()
        p.start()
        plist.append(p)

    print 'waiting for processes to join ...'
    for p in plist:
        p.join()

    print 'master is done'

master()
print 'script is done'
```

My questions:

1. How is `multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore` different from `multiprocessing.Manager().BoundedSemaphore`?
2. When would one want to use `multiprocessing.Manager().BoundedSemaphore` where using `multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore` instead would have produced a different result?